# Powershell Move Most recent File

Tags: powershell, move

I have a directory lets call it C:\MoveFile
within this directory are thousands of files similarly named

- Name                       Date Modified
- Dog_123123_Grey.doc       18/11/2015
- Dog_123123_Grey (2).doc   19/11/2015
- Dog_123123_Grey (3).doc   17/11/2015
- Cat_123123_Blue (3).doc   01/01/2015
- Cat_123123_Pink (6).doc   07/04/2015
- Cat_123123_Pink (7).doc   10/04/2015

Now if the version number in the file name was consistently numbered (2) etc it would be easy, however what I want to do is have powershell run through the items in the directory and move the most recent file based on the date modified to a new file location so that from the list provided the new directory will contain.

Name                         Date Modified

- Dog_123123_Grey (2).doc   19/11/2015
- Cat_123123_Blue (3).doc   01/01/2015
- Cat_123123_Pink (7).doc   10/04/2015

Now as far as my head can get with this is,

```
gci C:\MoveFile\*.doc | sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -first 1 | cpi -dest c:\NewDirectory
```

Which I haven't tested as I know its not complete and will not do what I need it to do, being honest there I know that somehow I need to ignore anything that is in the brackets e.g. (3) which I don't know how to do.  I had considered looking at 'somehow' only looking at the first 15 digits but some of the file names may be longer or shorter than this.

Scratching my head in frustration, anyone with more experience than I have any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your two "cat" files in your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you might want to do is:

1. Group files by name (excluding the version in the filename)
2. Sort the files in each group individually
3. Pick the most recent from each group

To get the filename without the version number, we can use the `-replace` regex operator to remove any set of parentheses containing one or more digits at the end of the `BaseName` string (the filename exlcuding the file extension):

```
PS C:\> 'Cat_123123_Blue (3)' -replace '\(\d+\)$',''
Cat_123123_Blue
```

So, to group them by this string, we do:

```
$FileGroups = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Movefile\ -Filter *.doc |Group-Object { ($_.BaseName -replace '\(\d+\)$','').Trim() }
```

Then iterate over our array of groups:

```
$FileGroups |ForEach-Object { 
    # Sort each group, grab the most recent file
    $RecentFile = $_.Group |Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |Select -First 1 # Copy it
    Copy-Item $RecentFile.FullName -Destination C:\NewFolder\
}
```

Comment: Hehe very close to my approach :)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your need correctly, here is a script that will help you list the files to move (PS 3.0 needed for the `-File` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`).

Here I create a new `Group` property in which I remove the "version number" to obtain a kind of "key" to group the items.

I list the files, sort them by descending `LastWriteTime`, and then group them by `Group` and take the first item of each group.

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\MoveFile"

$files = Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder -File |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object *,@{ n = "Group"; e = { $_.Name -replace "\s\(\d+\)","" } }

$filesToMove = $files | Group-Object Group | % {
    $_.Group | Select-Object -First 1
}

$filesToMove | Select-Object Name,LastWriteTime
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

I was playing a bit longer then the other guys, but arrived to the same conclusion:

```
$Folder = '\\Folder'
$Groups = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder | Group-Object -Property {($_.Name -replace "\s\(\d+\)","")}

Foreach ($G in $Groups) {
    $G | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | 
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
}
```

Hehe, better late then never :P

Comment: Damn, no more votes for today : ) `Group-Object { ... }` roxxx ! You both taught me a very nice thing today ! Thanks ^^

Comment: No problem, glad you liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get those results with a single line to copy the newer 2 files:

```
gci $origin -Recurse| where{-not $_.PsIsContainer}| sort CreationTime -desc| select -first 2 | Copy-Item -Force -Destination $destination
```